# Drawing an overlay on a UIView

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics

I have a UIView that I draw a CGPath to and would like to draw an overlay onto the entire view itself, one z level above the rendered CGPath.

How is this done? Should I use a layer? I would like to draw or fill parts of the view repeatedly, so I am not sure if it might be better to use some kind of fill method. Is there a more efficient way to fill parts of the view other than drawing a new path?

I want to create the effect similar to a progress bar, extending the overlays width during runtime depending on a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subview (or, similarly, a sub-layer) for this. A subview of a view will appear above the content rendered in `drawRect:`.

If you can get away with using a `UIImage` background (say, one created with `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`), and simply changing the size of that view over time, it will likely be more efficient than redrawing in `drawRect:`.

Comment: I already draw the view using drawRect, and would like this overlay ontop of it.

Comment: Right; I'm saying that you should use a subview for your overlay, and simply resize that subview to change the size of your overlay. I'm not sure what view you're talking about when you say you want to "draw or fill parts of the view repeatedly"; can you clarify what you want to draw/change over time?

Comment: No need, extending it on the y positive will be perfect, I can just set the background of the subview. Thanks! :)